# CHEMBL : Can't import new_client from chembl_webresource_client.new_client

Tags: python, jupyter

I have installed the **chembl_webresource_client** package.

Then I tried to import a module from the package:

```
from chembl_webresource_client.new_client import new_client
```

But it fails to execute and this error appears:

> ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call
> last)  in ()
> 1 # Import necessary libraries
> 2 import pandas as pd
> ----> 3 from chembl_webresource_client.new_client import new_client
>
> 4 frames
> /usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/chembl_webresource_client/cache.py
> in ()
> 1 **author** = 'mnowotka'
> 2
> ----> 3 from requests_cache.backends.base import BaseCache, hashlib, _to_bytes
> 4
> 5 def create_key(self, request):
>
> ImportError: cannot import name 'hashlib' from
> 'requests_cache.backends.base'
> (/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/requests_cache/backends/base.py)

Is there a fix for this?

Answer (score 0):

I have faced the same issue today and resolved it by updating **chembl-webresource-client** library's version from **0.10.2** to **0.10.3** in my project's **requirements.txt** file.

For example: *chembl-webresource-client==0.10.3*

Also after making these changes and activating your project's virtual environment, please don't forget to fetch and re-install all listed libraries in your **requirements.txt** using the following command:

**pip install -r .\requirements.txt**